# Using menu bars in desktop view with WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to substitute the word 'home' for menu bars in desktop view on my site, https://adsler.co.uk. I've found this piece of css which should work but doesn't seem to. Why not?

```
li#menu-item-1496:before
{content: '<';
visibility: hidden; 
} 
.dropdown:after { 
font-size: 16px; 
content: "\f0c9"; 
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="module widget-handle 
mobile-toggle right 
visible-sm visible-xs"><i 
class="fa 
fa-bars"></i></div><div 
class="module-group right"><div 
class="module left"><div 
class="collapse navbar-collapse 
navbar-ex1-collapse"><ul 
id="menu" class="menu"><li 
id="menu-item-1496" 
class="menu-item menu-item-type- 
post_type menu-item- 
object-page menu-item-home 
current-menu-item 
page_item page-item-19 
current_page_item menu-item- 
has-children menu-item-1496 
dropdown active"><a 
title="Home" 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/">Home 
</a>. 
<span class="dropdown-toggle 
shapely-dropdown" data-          
toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa- 
angle-down" aria- 
hidden="true"></i></span><ul 
role="menu" class=" 
dropdown-menu"><li id="menu-item- 
1502" class="fa fa- 
user menu-item menu-item-type- 
post_type menu-item- 
object-page menu-item-1502"><a 
title="Create Adsler
```

Comment: You can't **change** text that is in the HTML...you can only *style* it. I think you misunderstand what pseudo-elements actually do and are.

Comment: But this is WP....you shouldn't need CSS to change that text.

Comment: Hey. Just try this You can just go to Appearance -> Menus and choose to edit the menu that is being set as Primary(most probably). The CSS solution that I provided is a hack and will disturb other elements.

Answer (score 0):

The "Home" word is under the `#menu-item-1496 > a` selector. You're not pointing it, but its parent instead.

Anyways, you should find a much better way to replace a word other than CSS. It's WordPress, you should be able to do it.

Comment: Please see Manoj Kumar answer and comments. Thanks.